# How to change a specific categorical variable based on overall sequence of the data

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have collected data about plant development or phenology (coded using a categorical variable 'Code') every five days along a transect broken down into 78 consecutive segments. Each species is surveyed across the transect in each of the segments.

My study is repeating a 100 year ago historical study and I have kept the original phenology coding scheme without considering how I would analyze the data after the summer!

The problem that I did not consider when collecting the data is that the codes follow a sequence where one of the codes is repeated early and late over the summer. Specifically, the codes are:

```
b1 = single flower
b2 = sparse flowers (two or three)
b3 = flowers common (more than three)
B4 = flowering ended
```

Based on the methodology of the original study, the sequence of codes collected over the summer for any flowering plant will go something like, b1, b2, b3, b2, b1, b4. Note that we visit the transect every five days and the codes maybe repeated during consecutive days, e.g. b1, b1, b2, b2, b2, b2, b3, b3, b3, b2, b2, b1, b4.

I would like to re-code the 'b1' and 'b2' codes as follows (see example and sample data):

1. if 'b1' occurs before 'b2' or 'b3' then it should be 'b1a' and if it occurs after 'b2' or 'b3' then it should be 'b1b'. Note that sometimes there is not a 'b2' or 'b3' in the sequence of observations.

2. if 'b2' occurs before 'b3' then it should be 'b2a' and if it occurs after the 'b3' it should be 'b2b'. *OR* if there is no 'b3' then 'b2' should be 'b2a'. Note it is important to remember that after the last occurrence of 'b3' there maybe multiple observations of 'b2' (see example and sample data).

3. Consider that 'b1' and 'b2' might occur without and observation of 'b3', In this case, both would be coded as 'b1a' and 'b2a'.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2
19-Jun-17   1   A   b2
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b3
03-Jul-17   1   A   b2
08-Jul-17   1   A   b2
14-Jul-17   1   A   b1
19-Jul-17   1   A   b4
23-Jul-17   1   A   b4
```

This is what it should look like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1a
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2a
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2a
19-Jun-17   1   A   b2a
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b3
03-Jul-17   1   A   b2b
08-Jul-17   1   A   b2b
14-Jul-17   1   A   b1b
19-Jul-17   1   A   b4
23-Jul-17   1   A   b4
```

Here is the sample data:

```
Test.Data<- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 
17336, 17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17318, 17323, 
17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 
17370, 17375, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 
17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 
17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17370, 17375, 17355, 
17361, 17366, 17370, 17375, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17370
), class = "Date"), Segment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Species = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
), Code = c("b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b2", 
"b4", "b4", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b2", 
"b2", "b1", "b4", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", 
"b2", "b2", "b4", "b4", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b3", 
"b2", "b2", "b2", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b4", 
"b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b4")), .Names = c("Date", "Segment", 
"Species", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I have updated the example after exploring the data further using @Roland excellent solution to discover "unexpected" data sequences that of course should be expected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Test.Data)
Test.Data[, temp := rleid(Code), by = .(Segment, Species)] #unique ids for the sequence of codes
Test.Data[Code == "b2", Code := paste0(Code, letters[rleid(temp)]), 
  by = .(Segment, Species)] #use the unique ids inside subset
Test.Data[, temp := NULL]
#          Date Segment Species Code
# 1: 2017-06-01       1       A   b1
# 2: 2017-06-06       1       A   b1
# 3: 2017-06-10       1       A  b2a
# 4: 2017-06-14       1       A  b2a
# 5: 2017-06-19       1       A  b2a
# 6: 2017-06-23       1       A   b3
# 7: 2017-06-28       1       A   b3
# 8: 2017-07-03       1       A  b2b
# 9: 2017-07-08       1       A  b2b
#10: 2017-07-14       1       A   b4
#11: 2017-07-19       1       A   b4
#12: 2017-06-01       1       B   b1
#13: 2017-06-06       1       B  b2a
#14: 2017-06-10       1       B  b2a
#15: 2017-06-14       1       B  b2a
#16: 2017-06-19       1       B   b3
#17: 2017-06-23       1       B   b3
#18: 2017-06-28       1       B   b3
#19: 2017-07-03       1       B  b2b
#20: 2017-07-08       1       B  b2b
#21: 2017-07-14       1       B  b2b
#</cont>
```

Comment: thanks. This gives me a great place to start. My dataset (140000 observations) has a lot of other phenology codes related to other aspects of their development (e.g. leaf growth and fruit development). I will be able to subset my data, then use your code and then re-insert it into the original dataset. Also, your method assumes the data is sorted by 'Date', 'Segment' and 'Species' before running the code.

Comment: Sorting is extremely fast and easy for data.tables. Your example appeared to be sorted.

Comment: Is it possible to add the sort command into the simplified code? Test.Data[order(Segment, Species, Date)]

Comment: I wouldn't call chaining "simplified code". Just start the chaining with `DT[order(...)]` .

Comment: I have updated the example after exploring the data further using your excellent solution to discover "unexpected" data sequences that of course should be expected!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
Test.Data %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(hadb3 = cumsum(Code=="b3")>0) %>%
  mutate(Code = ifelse(Code=="b2" & !hadb3,"b2a",Code)) %>% 
  mutate(Code = ifelse(Code=="b2" & hadb3,"b2b",Code))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 48 x 5
# Groups:   Species [2]
         Date Segment Species  Code hadb3
       <date>   <dbl>   <chr> <chr> <lgl>
 1 2017-06-01       1       A    b1 FALSE
 2 2017-06-06       1       A    b1 FALSE
 3 2017-06-10       1       A   b2a FALSE
 4 2017-06-14       1       A   b2a FALSE
 5 2017-06-19       1       A   b2a FALSE
 6 2017-06-23       1       A    b3  TRUE
 7 2017-06-28       1       A    b3  TRUE
 8 2017-07-03       1       A   b2b  TRUE
 9 2017-07-08       1       A   b2b  TRUE
10 2017-07-14       1       A    b4  TRUE
# ... with 38 more rows
```

`mutate(hadb3 = cumsum(Code=="b3")>0)` creates a logical column that checks whether `b3` has appeared before and that is enough to get the result with ifelse statements.