# R How to drop inconsistent values in a sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

As stated in a previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444598/how-to-change-a-specific-categorical-variable-based-on-overall-sequence-of-the-d), I have collected data about plant development or phenology (coded using a categorical variable 'Code') every five days along a transect broken down into 78 consecutive segments. Each species is surveyed across the transect in each of the segments.

Another problem that I did not consider when collecting the data is that sometimes the observers might miss an observation in the field effecting the code they choose OR they simply made a typo. Specifically, the codes they used are:

```
b1 = single flower
b2 = sparse flowers (two or three)
b3 = flowers common (more than three)
B4 = flowering ended
```

The expected (simplified) sequence of observations over time would look something like 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b2', 'b1', 'b4'. Note that there can be multiple sample dates with the same observations, so the data may look like 'b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b3', 'b2', 'b2', 'b2', 'b1', 'b1', 'b4'.

Unfortunately, I have found numerous examples where the sequence looks like

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2
19-Jun-17   1   A   b3
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b2 # out of sequence - assume it should be b3
02-Aug-17   1   A   b3
07-Aug-17   1   A   b2 # out of sequence - assume it should be b3
12-Aug-17   1   A   b3
17-Aug-17   1   A   b2
22-Aug-17   1   A   b1 # out of sequence - assume it should be b2
27-Aug-17   1   A   b2 
02-Sep-17   1   A   b1
07-Sep-17   1   A   b4
```

It should look like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2
19-Jun-17   1   A   b3
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b3
02-Aug-17   1   A   b3
07-Aug-17   1   A   b3
12-Aug-17   1   A   b3
17-Aug-17   1   A   b2
22-Aug-17   1   A   b2
27-Aug-17   1   A   b2
02-Sep-17   1   A   b1
07-Sep-17   1   A   b4
```

A more **honest** approach would be to drop the first value that is out of sequence assuming we cannot know if the observer missed on observation of a flowering plant or it was a typo on the dataset. So, how do I drop the first value that that is out of sequence each time there is a sequence error? In this case the dataset would look like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2
19-Jun-17   1   A   b3
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
02-Aug-17   1   A   b3
12-Aug-17   1   A   b3
17-Aug-17   1   A   b2
22-Aug-17   1   A   b2
02-Sep-17   1   A   b1
07-Sep-17   1   A   b4
```

Here is example code:

```
Test.Data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17318, 17323, 17327,
17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17380, 17385, 17390, 17395, 17400, 17405, 
17411, 17416, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 
17380, 17385, 17390, 17395, 17400, 17405, 17411, 17416, 17318, 
17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17380, 17385, 17390, 
17395, 17400, 17405, 17411, 17416), class = "Date"), Segment = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2), Species = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Code = c("b1", 
"b1", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b1", 
"b2", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b3", 
"b2", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", 
"b3", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b1", "b4"
)), .Names = c("Date", "Segment", "Species", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = "data.frame")
```

Of course this **assumes** that the first time an observation of a plant flowering event for a given species (i.e. 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4') is correct!

Note: This question is reflects my desire to recode my dataset to overcome the deficiency of the original studies coding system (see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444598/how-to-change-a-specific-categorical-variable-based-on-overall-sequence-of-the-d)). If I had considered working with the data before the field season, I would have using a coding system like:

```
b1a = single flower
b2a = sparse flowers (two or three)
b3 = flowers common (more than three)
b2b = sparse flowers (two or three)
b1b = single flower
B4 = flowering ended
```

Regardless, I would still need to overcome this coding issue with the historic dataset!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Is the problem that it should be impossible to come from phase 3 to phase 2 and then back to phase 3 again? If so. you could use the lag() function to check previous rows and make some sort of if/else classifier based on your assumptions.

Comment: It is fine for the sequence to be b1, b2, b3, b3, b2, b1, b4. But is unlikely to be, e.g. b1, b2, b3, b2 (or b1), b3, b2, b1, b4. So we would not expect b3 (= more than three flowers) to occur over multiple dates with an intermediate observation to be 'b2'. An observation of 'b1' or 'b2' could however occur after the last observation of 'b3'! Does this help?

Comment: I am repeating a study from 100 years ago. I have to analyze the historical and contemporary data sets. I thought I was being smart by using the original coding system! In 1917 the data was published but not analyzed and now I see the errors of my ways!

Comment: Are you sure that the flowering period is short enough in comparison with the duration of a single flower to forbid the transitions you want to reject ?

Comment: Are study site is at 68 N latitude in the Swedish mountains and the flowering period is VERY short. I agree that this is an assumption, but we were often working in the clouds and it was easy to miss individual plants (for some species). I am trying to plot and compare phenology curves between 1917 (-1919) and our contemporary repeat of the study. Your suggestions are welcome!

Comment: In a sequence like `2 1 2 1` (e.g. from 17-Aug to 02-Sep-17), how can you tell that it is the second `2` which is wrong, and not the first `1`?

Comment: We are making an ASSUMPTION that the first observation in correct, in this case 2. In your example, 2 1 2 1 the expected values should be 2 2 2 1.

Comment: Yes, of course I meant 'assumption'...;)

Comment: Alternatively, I could just drop the observation that is out sequence. Maybe this makes more sense and is more honest?

Comment: In your question, the sequence `2 1 2 1` from 17-Aug to 02-Sep-17 is translated to `2 1 1 1` (i.e. the second `2` is assumed to be wrong), but here you write `2 2 2 1`. Sorry, I don't get it ;)

Comment: That is a darned good question! You are right that could be in reality either 2 2 2 1 or 2 1 1 1. In this case, my only option is to drop the first inconsistent value. Another **assumption**!

Comment: Is this really a question about R? Maybe better feedback could be obtained by moving it to either https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yes, this is a R question, it was the other users who helped me clarify my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility which relies on `cummax`.

```
# extract numbers from 'Code', except the last which I assume always is 4
x <- as.numeric(substring(d$Code[-length(d$Code)], 2))

# find index of first max
ix <- which.max(x == max(x))

# find cumulative max on
# (1) x from index 1 to ix
# (2) x from end to index ix + 1
# reverse (2)
# concatenate (1), (2) and a 4
d$Code2 <- c(cummax(x[1:ix]), rev(cummax(x[length(x):(ix + 1)])), 4)

d[ , c("Code", "Code2")]
   Code Code2
1    b1     1
2    b1     1
3    b2     2
4    b2     2
5    b3     3
6    b3     3
7    b2     3
8    b3     3
9    b2     3
10   b3     3
11   b2     2
12   b1     2
13   b2     2
14   b1     1
15   b4     4
```

---

To do this by 'Segment' and 'Species', you can use e.g. `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Test.Data)
Test.Data[ , Code2 := {
  x = as.numeric(substring(Code[-.N], 2))
  ix = which.max(x == max(x))
  .(paste0("b", c(cummax(x[1:ix]), rev(cummax(x[length(x):(ix + 1)])), 4)))
},
by = .(Segment, Species)]
```

Comment: This looks tantalizing, but as my R skills are still novice, I am not sure how to apply this code across the larger dataset (see example above) with multiple segment and species. I am new to data.tables.

Comment: @KeithW.Larson Updated with 'by-group' code, here using `data.table`.

Comment: Sorry, basically I hate my question! Your code works fine on the sample dataset, but because my complete dataset is very large, there always seems to be a scenario that I did not account for in my sample dataset. What is the protocol here? Should I accept your answer, delete my question, or is their another alternative?

Comment: No need for neither accepting or deleting. Just leave it as it is. If my answer solved the problem _as described in the question_, you may consider accepting it. That said: "[Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)". If your new problem is sufficiently different from the current, just ask a new question.